# Replace words in html with links, but prefer longer words if search term collide

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I am having trouble with the following task:

I need to enrich a string containing html by linking some of the words it contains to "read more" pages. Unfortunately when the search terms I want to replace begin to overlap it becomes tricky.
I either end up with nested links or, like in the example below, with longer terms not being replaced.

```js
let html = `<p>So there is this Text in HTML containing words.</p>
<p>I want to link some special words to their read more pages.</p>
<p>But if search terms contain each other they re not linked correctly. Like the ones above.</p>`;

const linkTo = [
    {term: 'words', link: 'https://example.com/words'},
    {term: 'special words', link: 'https://example.com/special_words'},
];

for(const pair of linkTo){
    const re = new RegExp(pair.term, "g");
    html = html.replace(re, `<a href="${pair.link}">${pair.term}</a>`);
}

document.body.innerHTML = html;
```

```html
<html><body></body></html>
```

In the example above the "special words" in line 2 should link to its own page.

Any Ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question needs clarification. Its hard (for me) to decipher what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @GetSet It is very clear in fact.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm lost

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65341563/3832970).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to sort the keys by length in the descending order and create a single regex from the terms:

```js
let html = `<p>So there is this Text in HTML containing words.</p>
<p>I want to link some special words to their read more pages.</p>
<p>But if search terms contain each other they re not linked correctly. Like the ones above.</p>`;

const linkTo = [
    {term: 'words', link: 'https://example.com/words'},
    {term: 'special words', link: 'https://example.com/special_words'},
];
const keys = linkTo.map(x => x.term).sort((a, b) => b.length-a.length)
const re = new RegExp("\\b(?:" + keys.join("|") + ")\\b", "g");
html = html.replace(re, (m) => `<a href="${linkTo.find(x => m == x.term).link}">${m}</a>`);
document.body.innerHTML = html;
```

```html
<html><body></body></html>
```

Note I am not escaping special chars for the time being since all your terms consist of word chars, and that is why I add `\b` on both ends, word boundaries.

In case you need to search for terms that may contain special chars you will need to use

```js
const keys = linkTo.map(x => x.term.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')).sort((a, b) => b.length-a.length)
const re = new RegExp("(?<!\\w)(?:" + keys.join("|") + ")(?!\\w)", "g");
```

Some more details:

- `linkTo.map(x => x.term).sort((a, b) => b.length-a.length)` - gets the `terms` from the `linkTo` items and sorts them by length in descending order, the longer come first. It is necessary because [The Regex Engine Is Eager](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html#eager) and the first alternative "wins" and make the regex engine stop processing other alternatives
- `new RegExp("\\b(?:" + keys.join("|") + ")\\b", "g")` build a regex like `\b(?:special words|words)\b`
- `` .replace(re, (m) => `<a href="${linkTo.find(x => m == x.term).link}">${m}</a>`) `` - parses a string only once, and replaces each match with the corresponding `link`.

Special chars supporting solution:

```js
let html = `<p>So there is this Text in HTML containing words.</p>
<p>I want to link some special words to their read more pages.</p>
<p>But if search terms contain each other they re not linked correctly. Like the ones above.</p>`;

const linkTo = [
    {term: 'words', link: 'https://example.com/words'},
    {term: 'special words', link: 'https://example.com/special_words'},
];
const keys = linkTo.map(x => x.term.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')).sort((a, b) => b.length-a.length)
const re = new RegExp("(\\W|^)(" + keys.join("|") + ")(?!\\w)", "g");
html = html.replace(re, (x,y,z) => `${y}<a href="${linkTo.find(i => z == i.term).link}">${x}</a>`);
document.body.innerHTML = html;
```

Comment: This seems to work perfectly :)
When I deploy it to devices I get "SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: invalid group specifier name" on the line that creates the RegExp() in react native. Do you happen to know what that could be?

Comment: I am using the second version for special chars btw.

Comment: @janrop Do you use it in Safari? It does not support lookbehinds. I added a snippet, please check.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the `string.replace()` function:

```js
let html = `<p>So there is this Text in HTML containing words.</p>
<p>I want to link some special words to their read more pages.</p>
<p>But if search terms contain each other they re not linked correctly. Like the ones above.</p>`;

const linkTo = [
    {term: 'words', link: 'https://example.com/words'},
    {term: 'special words', link: 'https://example.com/special_words'},
];

for(const pair of linkTo){
   html = html.replace(pair.term, `<a href="${pair.link}">${pair.term}</a>`);
}

document.body.innerHTML = html;
```

```html
<html><body></body></html>
```

Comment: This does not replace the words globally unfortunately. I need every occurrence of the word replaced. It only works with the example code on accident.